# Free software to run online visual category learning experiment

Tags: cognitive-psychology, learning, experimental-psychology, software, visualization

Is there any open software to support a visualization category learning experiment? It should be open-source, and I can add more functions designed by myself to implement this experiment.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [jsPsych](http://www.jspsych.org), which is an open-source JavaScript library for building experiments. There is an [example of running a visual categorization task](https://github.com/jodeleeuw/jsPsych/wiki/jspsych-categorize) in the documentation for the library.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some open-source software for you:

- [PsychoPy](http://www.psychopy.org/)
- [OpenSesame](http://osdoc.cogsci.nl/)
- [PEBL](http://pebl.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Any more direct links as to how to use these packages to set up visual category learning experiments specifically?

Comment: You simply must design your experiment and write some code or use GUI to realize your design in one of this program. There are no existing solutions, but there are useful tutorials and friendly community.

Answer (score 1):

I've been developing an online platform to run HTML5/Javascript experiments, recruit participants via email, facebook, or twitter, and collect and evaluate results in real time.

The platform itself is not open source but many of the experiments are right now and more will be soon. You may also add your own experiments if you are comfortable developing HTML5/Javascript.

Please see http://statode-demo.herokuapp.com/mental-rotation/ for a demo, it does not require signup.